# Docker-compose mysql does not seem to recognize environment variable MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup mysql to run in a docker container. I have a simple docker compose file :-

```
db:
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes
```

when i run the docker-compose file, I get the following warning in docker logs instead of the random generated password.

> [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please
>   consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tried the same and it worked. I think you're missing something in the logs. In the beginning there appears:

> root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider
>   switching off the --initialize-insecure option.

But check a bit later. The keys are created and a bit further you'll find something like this:

> GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: Cet6Xeiheecohleal9uexxxxDathah

You can find it more easy by using this command (replace with your container ID):

```
docker logs da530043c63a 2>/dev/null | grep "GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD"
```

Comment: Thanks. I see the password now.

Comment: I have explicitly set `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=superstrongpassword` and still received that warning. But am I right to guess that MySQL still set the root password correctly after initialization is complete?

Comment: you're just checking the logs too quickly after starting the container :) Give it a minute and you'll see it in the logs